# Separate counter for each list in zip_longest() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm using Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10.  My code:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def uniqify(passedlist):
    seen = set()
    unique = []
    duplicate = []

    for item in passedlist:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)            
            duplicate.append("")    # add empty string for formatting output
            unique.append(item)
        elif item in seen:
            duplicate.append(item)
            unique.append("")   # add empty string for formatting output

    return unique, duplicate



listFruits = ["apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "banana", "peach", "cherry", "cherry"]

listUnique, listDuplicate = uniqify(listFruits)

print(f"Fruits\t\tUnique\t\tDuplicates")
print(f"------\t\t------\t\t----------")

for num, (fruit, unique, duplicate) in enumerate(zip_longest(listFruits, listUnique, listDuplicate), start=1):
    print(f"{num}: {fruit}\t{unique}\t\t{duplicate}")
```

Current output:

```py
Fruits          Unique          Duplicates
------          ------          ----------
1: apple        apple
2: orange       orange
3: orange                       orange
4: banana       banana
5: banana                       banana
6: banana                       banana
7: peach        peach
8: cherry       cherry
9: cherry                       cherry
```

I'm looking to have a separate counter for `listUnique` and `listDuplicate` within the `for` loop.

Desired output:

```py
Fruits          Unique          Duplicates
------          ------          ----------
1: apple        1. apple
2: orange       2. orange
3: orange                       1. orange
4: banana       3. banana
5: banana                       2. banana
6: banana                       3. banana
7: peach        4. peach
8: cherry       5. cherry
9: cherry                       4. cherry
```

I've searched all over the Internet for this, but I couldn't find the solution.  I'm currently thinking of just creating separate lists within `uniqify()`, with numbers, and inserting empty strings for formatting output.

Is there a way to have separate counters for lists when using `zip_longest()`?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does your `unique` column contain items which are not unique, such as orange, banana and cherry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just manually count as you loop:

```
uniq_count, dupe_count = 0, 0

for num, (fruit, unique, duplicate) in enumerate(zip_longest(listFruits, listUnique, listDuplicate), start=1):
    if unique:
        uniq_count += 1
        unique = f'{uniq_count}. {unique}'
    if duplicate:
        dupe_count += 1
        duplicate = f'{dupe_count}. {duplicate}'
    print(f"{num}: {fruit}\t{unique}\t\t{duplicate}")
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a counter and adding that counter as prefix to your lists ?
like this

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

    for item in passedlist:
        
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            count1 = count1 + 1
            duplicate.append("")
            lol = str(count1) + ". " + str(item)
            unique.append(lol)
            
        elif item in seen:
            count2 = count2 + 1
            lolwa = "    " + str(count2) + ". " + str(item)
            unique.append("")
            duplicate.append(lolwa)
```

I know this isn't an elegant solution.

Comment: I was initially thinking of doing this, but I decided against it, since I need to use the returned lists later on in my code for other operations.